# Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist when trying to login to a user

Tags: php, laravel, session, guard

My application creates users that derive from a Spreadsheet. They login with their "personal informatio"' then create a password for the account. Sort of like a soft login at first, then they complete the registration by claiming the account.

Once the "soft login" has occurred, and the account is "claimed", every time a user logs in softly my middleware redirects them to a password page where they then input their password.

Once they have done so, I need to verify that this is the correct password. So far, I do this:

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt([
        // Auth::user() works because they are "soft logged in"
        // However, middleware prevents all routes until they authenticate
        // Their password once the accounts claimed
        'id' => Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier(),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    ])) {
        DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())
                ->where('user_agent', '=', $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT'))
                ->update([
                    'authenticated' => true
                ]);

        return redirect(route('dashboard'));
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Invalid password. Please try again.']);
}
```

The issue I get is that the `attempt` gives me this error:

```
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.
```

I checked my Guards in my `Auth.php` config file:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

And the `driver` is set to `session` so I'm unsure now what could be causing this issue. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have solved this with using `password_verify()`

```
        $hash = DB::table('users')->select('password')
                ->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())
                ->get()
                ->all()[0]->password;

        if(password_verify($request->input('password'), $hash)) {
            DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())
                    ->where('user_agent', '=', $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT'))
                    ->update([
                        'authenticated' => true
                    ]);

            return redirect(route('dashboard'));
        }
```